# How to merge keys based on value in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I am wondering if there was a way to merge keys together based on same values in the Hashmap. 
Ex.

```
A->2
B->1
C->2
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
2 - A, C
1 - B
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is to have your map defined like this:

```
Map<String,List<String>> multiValueMap = new HashMap();
```

Or if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, then use [Apache MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Comment: Or use Guava Multimap equal to Apache, just another Library. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the data structure to store data in this way. Use a `HashMap` of `ArrayList` or `Set` (*as appropriate for you*) to do this.

Example

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('A', 2);
map.put('B', 1);
map.put('c', 2);

// SORTED
HashMap<Integer, List<Character>> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
    list = sortedMap.get(entry.getValue());
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        entry.put(entry.getValue(), list);
    }
    list.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: `HashMap` is *not* a sorted map. --- Why call `containsKey()`? Just call `get()` and check for `null`, instead of requiring 2 hash lookups.

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap Reversal**

```
HashMap<String,Integer> aHM = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> aHMrev = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
//HashMap Reversal
for (String f : aHM.keySet()){
    if(aHMrev.get(aHM.get(f)) != null){
        ArrayList<String> al = aHMrev.get(aHM.get(f));
        al.add(f);
        aHMrev.put(aHM.get(f), al);
    }
    else{
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(f);
        aHMrev.put(aHM.get(f), al);
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
    aHM = [LMWEB1B-VMH.log=Group1,PLMWEB1E-VMH.csv=Group3, 
    LMWEB1A-VMH.log=Group1,
    LMWEB1E-VMH.log=Group2,
    PLMWEB1D-VMH.csv=Group3,
    LMWEB1F-VMH.log=Group2,
    PLMWEB1C-VMH.csv=Group3,
    PLMWEB1A-VMH.csv=Group2,
    PLMWEB1B-VMH.csv=Group3,
    PLMDB1-VMH.csv=Group2,
    LMWEB1D-VMH.log=Group1,
    PLMWEB1F-VMH.csv=Group3,
    LMWEB1C-VMH.log=Group1]

    aHMrev = {
    Group1=[LMWEB1B-VMH.log, LMWEB1A-VMH.log, LMWEB1D-VMH.log,LMWEB1C-VMH.log],
    Group2=[LMWEB1E-VMH.log, LMWEB1F-VMH.log,PLMWEB1A-VMH.csv,PLMDB1-VMH.csv],
    Group3=[D:\Trash\Logs\Perfmon\PLMWEB1E-VMH.csv,PLMWEB1D-VMH.csv,PLMWEB1C-VMH.csv,PLMWEB1B-VMH.csv,PLMWEB1F-VMH.csv]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just create `HaspMap` like below:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add("B");
map1.put(1, al);
al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add("A");
al.add("C");
map1.put(2, al);
```

Comment: This is not converting the `HashMap` that OP already has, and mixing single value and `String` array list that as an Object is not very typesafe,